# How to move a picture this pygame program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've got the code below, the image ain't moving. Please tell me what's wrong so I can fix it real quick. Also, try to keep the answers short and to the point.

I can hear the music and all, the escape button and the quit is working too, directional keys are not.

```
PlayerImage = pygame.image.load("ch.jpg")
Player = pygame.Rect(675, 350, 40, 4)
StretchPlayer = pygame.transform.scale(PlayerImage, (40, 40))

goLeft = False
goRight = False
goUp = False
goDown = False

Velocity = 3

EatSound = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.load("X.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
musicPlaying = True

while True :

    for event in pygame.event.get() :

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('A'):
                goRight = False
                goLeft = True

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('D'):
                goRight = True
                goLeft = False

            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('W'):
                goUp = True
                goDown = False

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('S'):
                goUp = False
                goDown = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('A'):
                goLeft = False

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('D'):
                goRight = False

            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('W'):
                goUp = False

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('S'):
                goDown = False

    DisplayScreen.blit(StretchPlayer, Player)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: where do you edit the `Rect`?

Comment: Oh yeah, maybe I forgot that =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the location of the rectangle `Player` dependent on `goLeft`, `goRight`, `goUp` and `goDown`, e.g. by [`.move`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move):

```py
dx = -1 if goLeft else 1 if goRight else 0
dy = -1 if goUp   else 1 if goDown  else 0
Player = Player.move(dx, dy)
DisplayScreen.blit(StretchPlayer, Player)
```